# Prevent inline-block elements from overflowing their parent

Tags: html, css, overflow

The text in the `span`s below overflows (see the fiddle). I can't figure out why.

**JSFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/8xuah0kn/

**HTML**

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Participant</th>
            <th>Car ID</th>
            <th>Score</th>
            <th>Round Totals</th>
            <th>Pro</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>X</td>
            <td>7/15</td>
            <td>Alfonso Ribeiro</td>
            <td>1001</td>
            <td>
                <div class="faux-row">
                    <span>Start</span>
                    <span>2003</span>
                </div>
                <div class="faux-row">
                    <span>End</span>
                    <span>2140</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>yes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>X</td>
            <td>7/15</td>
            <td>Joan Rodriguez</td>
            <td>1002</td>
            <td>
                <div class="faux-row">
                    <span>Start</span>
                    <span>100</span>
                </div>
                <div class="faux-row">
                    <span>End</span>
                    <span>0</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>yes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>X</td>
            <td>7/15</td>
            <td>Jeremy Johns</td>
            <td>1003</td>
            <td>
                <div class="faux-row">
                    <span>Start</span>
                  <span>1000200</span>
                </div>
                <div class="faux-row">
                    <span>End</span>
                  <span>1002232</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>yes</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```css
body {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.9em;
}
td:nth-child(1) {
    color: red;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
td:nth-child(4) {
    max-width: 60px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
td:nth-child(5) .faux-row {
    background-color: #def;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 2px;
}
td:nth-child(5) span:nth-child(1) {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    width: 46%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
td:nth-child(5) span:nth-child(2) {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
    width: 46%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td, th {
    border: 1px solid maroon;
    padding: 2px;
    text-align: center;
}
th {
    background-color: lightyellow;
}
```

**Things the above code is trying to achieve**:

- Keep the "Start/End" span pushed to the left, and its associated point number to the right.
- Prevent point number from wrapping to the next line
- Do it without hard-coding in a large width in pixels

Comment: Remove the width that you have set on the spans `width:46%`

Comment: @Danield The problem with that is that the spans are no longer pushed to the left and to the right. I'll make that requirement explicit in my question.

Comment: Try this and see if it'll work for your situation: Add a min-width on .faux-row, to prevent it from shrinking smaller than what you want - something like min-width:120px, or  min-width:9em for a flexible size.

Answer (score 0):

1) Remove the width

2) Add `text-align: left`; to the parent of the spans

3) Float the second span to right

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8xuah0kn/4/)**

```
td:nth-child(5) .faux-row {
    background-color: #def;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 2px;
    text-align: left; /* <-- */
}
td:nth-child(5) span:nth-child(2) {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right; /* <-- */
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 1px 0 0 10px; /* <-- */
}
```

Comment: It's really close! There's still one problem though... which is that when you resize the window, the floated element drops down. I guess I could fix that with a min-width on the table (or on a column)? Is there a cleaner way?